# AddLast method to array list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, addition

I am trying to create an AddLast method to an array list. I have been able to implement an AddFront method that works. However, I have tried to use statements from the AddFront method to the AddLast method.

This is my constructor

```
public ArrayList(int size)
        {
            array = new T[size];
        }
```

This is my counter.

```
int next = 0;
```

This is my Grow method.

```
private void Grow(int newsize)
        {
            T[] array2;
            newsize = array.Length * 2;
            array2 = new T[newsize];
            for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
            {
                array2[x] = array[x];
            }
            array = array2;
        }
```

This is my AddFront method.

```
 public void AddFront(T value) 
        {
            int position = 0;

            
                count++;
                if (count + 1 > array.Length)
                {
                    Grow(count + 1);
                }

                for (int i = count + 1; i > position; i--)
                {
                    array[i] = array[i - 1];
                }
                array[position] = value;
            


        }
```

This is my AddLast method

```
public void AddLast() 
        {
            count++;
            if (count + 1 > array.Length)
            {
                Grow(count + 1);
            }
            for(int i = count + 1; i <= count + 1; i++)
            {
                if ()
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use a `List<T>` that already provides this functionality? Or a `LinkedList<T>`? Or whichever collection works best in your situation.

Comment: Note in the blue box in the **Remarks** section for the `ArrayList` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1) that it says, *"We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class."*

Comment: Also, your code is incomplete. Where is the definition of `count` and `Grow`?

Comment: And you can just use the `Add` method of the `ArrayList` - it adds an item to the end of the array. If that's not what you want it to do, please define the desired functionality better (and `array.Insert(0, value)` will insert an item to the beginning of the array, which I assume is what `AddFront` should do?).

Comment: Please look at the code of `List<T>` to see how size should be managed (code does not seem to keep track of `count` correctly). Also it is unclear what should happen when you do `AddLast` - just add `default(T)` as `array[count]`?

Comment: This is a clear case of reinventing the wheel. As already mentioned here, both of these functionalities already exist in the ArrayList class. The fact that you choose to use ArrayList is a whole other story. You would have done that 19 years ago. Please use List<object> if you need to store disparate types, but a linked list would be a lot more efficient for this task... unless you really need index access.

Comment: @RufusL I am trying to loop through the list to the next available index that is null. Then insert the value into that index. However, I cannot use a linked list since I am using one in another class. I would like to implement the method to add a value to the list manually without using a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

The AddLast() method exists in the LinkedList class but not an ArrayList.
You can either:

- Switch to use a LinkedList or
- call Insert() method for ArrayList

As stated in the [docs.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.insert?view=netcore-3.1)

```
myAL.Insert( myAL.Count, "!!!" ); // Add "!!!" at the end.
```